# AWS Lambda (.NET) + SQS: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

i use AWS Lambda (.NET Core 2.1 environment) + SQS as trigger

The problem is that my lambda cannot parse my SQS message.

> Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON
>   strings must be quoted, for example "Hello World" in order to be
>   converted to a string: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.: JsonSerializerException

Here is declaration of my handler:

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(DummyMessage message, ILambdaContext context)
```

Model:

```
public class DummyMessage {
  public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

SQS input from AWS Console that I tried: `{"Label":"qwerty"}`, `"{"Label":"qwerty"}"`, `"{\"Label\":\"qwerty\"}"`, but same error occurs.

Could you please help with this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When passing Json try JObject from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
FunctionHandler(JObject eventStr, ILambdaContext context)
```

and then you can Deseralize the response where SQSEvent is inherited from Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents SDK Library.

```
var result = eventStr.ToObject<SQSEvent>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, do not forget to add/change aws serializer :

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
namespace AwsLambdaHandleTelegramWebhooks
{
   public class Function
   {
      public  APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(JObject input,ILambdaContext context)
      {
```

Answer (score 0):

What Solved My problem :
I used `[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer))]` on the Function Handler

and Assigned `[JsonProperty("")]` attribute to all POCO class Properties

and directly used the POCO class in the Handler Signature `FunctionHandler(MyPocoClass input, ILambdaContext context)`

The following is my Call in MAIN :

```
 private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<MyPocoClass , ILambdaContext, string> handler = FunctionHandler;
        await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer())
            .Build()
            .RunAsync();
    }
```

Following is My Handler Method:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer))]
public static string FunctionHandler(MyPocoClass input, ILambdaContext context)
{
   // logic
}
```

MyPoco Class :

```
public class MyPocoClass
{
     [JsonProperty("MyProperty")]
     public string? MyProperty{ get; set; }
    
}
```